# Performance Issues with UITextView and TextKit 2 in Large Text Documents

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, textkit

I've been working with `UITextView` and TextKit 2, which became the default text engine since iOS 16, and I've encountered performance issues when handling very large text documents.

Even on iPhone 14 Pro, I've noticed stuttering and frame drops when scrolling through the text view containing a large amount of text.

To reproduce the issue, you can use the following code:

```swift
// In iOS 16
let textView = UITextView()
textView.text = "some really large string (say 1 million characters)"
```

The scrolling performance in this scenario is not smooth. However, if you switch to TextKit 1 by accessing the `layoutManager` property, the performance significantly improves:

```swift
// In iOS 16
let textView = UITextView()
let _ = textView.layoutManager  // this enables the compatibility mode
textView.text = "some really large string (say 1 million characters)"
```

With this code, scrolling remains smooth even with large text documents. It's very disappointing to see TextKit 2 performing worse than TextKit 1, even though Apple claims TextKit 2 has significantly improved performance with noncontiguous layout.

Furthermore, the sample code for TextKit 2, available [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/textkit/using_textkit_2_to_interact_with_text), crashes when handling very large text due to excessive memory usage.

Has anyone else experienced similar performance issues with TextKit 2, and are there any potential solutions or workarounds to improve the performance?

Comment: I am struggling with similar issues. Did you find any solution that uses Text Kit 2 ?

Comment: Just had similar memory issue with custom UITextView, found that setting custom font to the textView causes repeated allocations for each line and eventually the app crashes. I am not sure about TextKit2 or its implementation, but be sure to check out the font of the textView eventually. I had tested with 8 MB input file with 200K lines and after commenting out custom font set line, the hang/freeze is gone.